# Aligned equations in tables

Tags: tables

I'm new to LaTeX. I'm trying to create a table where one of the cells contains aligned equations.

The naive approach of nesting an align environment inside the table environment does not work:

```
\begin{tabular}{l r}
A & B\\
\begin{align}
x &= y+1\\
x &= (y+1) (y-1)
\end{align}
\end{tabular}
```

This gives the error 'Argument of \align has an extra }.'

I must admit I have no idea what that error message means... Why is it not possible to nest align and table environments? How do I put aligned equations in a table?

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: This question is very similar in nature to [Two columns of equations, aligned and just one number per column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114020/5764). You should "hide" the `align` alignment character `&` from the `tabular` by bracing it.

Comment: similar, but with more and clearer answers than the question linked by @Werner: [Align equations inside tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148347/579)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't use an `align` (or `align*`) environment inside a `tabular` environment, unless you go to some lengths to "hide" the `align` environment.

A simple remedy is available: Use an `aligned` environment. Optionally, use a `[t]` or `[b]` placement specifier to specify if you want **t**op- or **b**ottom-alignment. If you don't provide a placement indicator, any adjacent material will be centered vertically relative to the material in the `aligned` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
A & B\\
\hline
$\begin{aligned}[t] % placement: default is "center", options are "top" and "bottom"
x &= y+1\\
x &= (y+1) (y-1)
\end{aligned}$ & abc xyz\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for option [t].